# Snapshot created 0 byte on Debian server (Google cloud Engine)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, snapshot

Checking my scheduled snapshot (Google Cloud Engine / Debian apache server + SSD 100gb)
I realized that scheduled snapshots are 0 bytes. The same result creating new snapshot manually.

Snapshots worked until two weeks ago.

How to restore the integrated snapshot functionality?

Answer (score 1):

Snapshots are incremental by default to avoid billing for redundant data and to minimize use of storage space.

However, to ensure the reliability of snapshot history, a snapshot might occasionally capture a full image of the disk.

For example, if the snapshot is scheduled daily

```
Day 1 - First snapshot of x1 GB
Day 2 - Delta of data between the previous snapshot (x1 GB) and current state (x2 GB) -> Snapshot size = x2 - x1 GB
Day 3 - Delta of data between the previous snapshot (x2 GB) and current state (x3 GB) -> Snapshot size = x3 - x2 GB
```

Refer [Creating frequent snapshots efficiently](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/snapshot-best-practices#efficient_snapshots)

Comment: I know that snapshots are incremental but we changed many data/files from last 2 weeks so, I'm thinking that is there some issues.

At this time generated snapshot of my google-cloud-engine is not working and I need to understand the reason instead of use command-line workaround.

Is there a tool that check if snapshot is working?

Comment: You can follow [this document](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/scheduled-snapshots#logging_and_monitoring) to view the logs for this operation - schedule snapshot and find the error messages.